# member "Node::next" (of a friend class) is inaccessible

Tags: c++, class, pointers, private

I am building my own `LinkedList`, because I need a special `Node` that holds more data. I specify that my `Node` class is a friend of the `LinkedList` class, but it doesn't seem to allow me to access the private variables in the `Node` class from the `LinkedList` class.

**Node.h**

```cpp
class Node {
    private:
        Node* next;
    ...
};
```

**LinkedList.h**

```cpp
#include "Node.h"

class LinkedList {
    friend class Node;
    ...
};
```

**LinkedList.cpp**

```cpp
...
void LinkedList::insertFirst(Node* n) {
    Node* temp = this->root;
    this->root = n;
    this->root->next = temp; // 1
}
...
```

<sup>1</sup> This is where I get the error. It says that the `this->root->next` is inaccessible, but I have it as a friend class to my `LinkedList` and so private variables should be accessible to it.

There are quite a few questions here on Stack Overflow that talk about something similar to my question, but none of them seem to be what I need.

- One answer was saying to switch from `private` to `protected`, but that didn't work, it just changed the error to say it can't access the protected member.
- Another answer was saying that they had a misspelling in there friend declaration. I checked mine, and it is spelled correctly.
- Another was saying to make sure that the classes are declared in the correct order, but since I have them in different files, and `#include` the file where I create the class that is declared as a friend.

There were quite a few more that I looked at, but all were similar to the above mentioned and didn't help me solve my problem.

What am I missing/not understanding? Nothing I've tried has worked, and I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: LinkedList should be a friend of Node

Comment: Friendship is *granted*; not *taken* (sorta like real life). `Node` has to offer it to `LinkedList` ; not the other way around.

Comment: @WhozCraig That makes sense, I guess I forgot that from my class I had about it quite a few years ago. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `friend` declaration grants access of the specified class to the private members of the declaring class (ie, "that class X over there is a friend of mine, he has permission to use my private stuff").

So, by declaring `Node` as a `friend` inside of `LinkedList`, you are granting `Node` access to `LinkedList`'s private members, not the other way around like you want.

To let `LinkedList` access `Node::next`, you need to declare `LinkedList` as a `friend` of `Node` instead:

```
class Node {
    friend class LinkedList;
    ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I either wasn't taught that (just shown it) or I forgot it, makes sense though. I appreciate the answer.